# Boy's father gets cloned by aliens and starts trying to abduct others on a hunting trip

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, clones

The boys father was cloned by an alien, boy suspects something wrong. The man took friends hunting in forest where they became cloned by aliens. The clones would then return home living normal life.  A sheriff helped the boy get rid of aliens. I think it was either 80 or 90s